# How to add Openssl library to existing Android project

Tags: android, android-studio, openssl

Could someone plese show me a step by step guide to do this in android studio. Every instruction guide I found is about installing it on Linux, not in Windows.

Found a prebuilt openssl for android in github. I wonder cloning it right into my project the right way to do?